# How to use more than 1 or 2 conditions in php if statements?

Tags: php

I want to output as per Condition, as I mentioned in the code. But I have 3 more conditions, That is - Medium, Large, and Extra large. These all are services.  can I mention all four conditions at a time and the output should be relivent!

Here is the code with if Statement :

```
if ($item['description'] == "Small") {
    $typeoutput = Lang::trans('invoicessacsms').'<br />';
    }
```

Please check the code above,  and suggest something. Thanks

Comment: You can use [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: `if($a==1){}elseif($a==2){}elseif($a==3){}else{}`

Comment: Will the result be the same for all services or should be different for each?

Comment: you can use `AND` and `OR` operators,if you need to include conditions in one line.You can also use `if {// code goes here} else if{// code goes here} else` for checking conditios

Comment: @Hanky Panky,  I want to consider them only in if ,not in else-if,  can't make it messy :(

Comment: `if(){}if(){}if(){}` is 1 million times messier than an elseif when you are dealing with 1 object which can have different values

Comment: We are sorry to be bad at guessing what you want while doing your job for you for free, BRO. And by the way, Jigar didn't use a `if` at all, it's a `switch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `Switch` cases like this for different results:

```
switch ($item['description']) {
    case 'small':
        $typeoutput = Lang::trans('invoicessacsms').'<br />';
        break;
    case 'Medium':
        # code...
        break;
    default:
        # code...
        break;
}
```

if results are same then you can use multiple condition in `if`

```
if (($item['description'] == 'small') || ($item['description'] == 'Medium')) { // use || or && depending upon your requirement
    $typeoutput = Lang::trans('invoicessacsms').'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for awesome suggestion Jigar, It's working.  Please, can you upvote to my question?  Thanks for the same :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply define an associative array in order to avoid using any other statement:

```
$translations = [
    'Small' => Lang::trans('invoicessacsms'),
    'Large' => Lang::trans('invoicelarge')
];

$typeout = $translations[$item['description']] . '<br />';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use logical operator.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

```
if($a && $b) // a AND b
if($a || $b) // a OR b
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the array of your value and check with [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) like below

```
$valArray = array ("small","large","medium");

if (in_array($item['description'],$valArray) ) {
    $typeoutput = Lang::trans('invoicessacsms').'<br />';
    }
```

> in_array — Checks if a value exists in an array